# Force light mode for specific app

Tags: dark-mode

I use my phone on dark mode, but there is a specific badly done app that uses black text on dark background when using dark mode. So, I want to use light mode only for that app.

How do I do that? I'd like something that isn't an app constantly running in the background, so something like an XPosed module would have the best performance. However, I'm open to non-root solutions, especially for anyone who's reading this question and doesn't have root.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the author of the problematic app? Often "delegating" the problem solution development to the developer is the easiest solution.

Comment: It would be good if you mention the device and Android version you are using. Xiaomi devices running MIUI offers a way to exclude user installed apps from dark mode. Have you tried searching your Settings to see if your ROM has this feature to exclude an app from dark mode?

Comment: @Robert I will but I have not yet. Firelord I have a mostly stock Android ROM